# Laptop touchpad problems when PSU charger (Original) is plugged in

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, power, touchpad

I have an HP laptop which battery is damaged since February of 2021. HP DIAGNOSTIC TOOLS tells me that
battery internal capacity is only at 10% of its factory capacity. The battery is also inflated. I am still using the battery because windows keeps me notified when I accidentally unplug the charger. Since two months ago, I have been suffering with my touchpad. Every time I plug in my charger, my touchpad moves erratically to every single direction. I thougth at the beginning that my touchpad was dirty outside and inside, so in cleaned up my whole PC. That did not solve the problem. I started to believe that the problem was caused by grounding problems in my house but this is not the case. Here you can find evidence of some test that I did to my outlet: [neutral and earth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKAXI.jpg), [neutral and phase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lfx1Z.jpg), [phase and earth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRj69.jpg). Also, there are the voltage measures on the cable: [phase and earth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gzIj.jpg), [neutral and phase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2cqv.jpg), [neutral and earth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCjqX.jpg).

Now, when I plug in the PSU charger on my pc, this is the
[output voltage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coEHr.jpg). Also the [specs of my charger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMBSk.jpg) (The one that I am using which came with the PC). The specs say that the input is between 100 and 240 V at 1.7A. And the output is 19.5 V at 3.33A.

I did an experiment which consist of the follow: I grabbed a copper cable and tied it on the tip of my charger plug (the one I connect to the PC). The other side of the cable were tied to my hand. Doing this, the touchpad stop moving erratically. But as soon as, I release the cable out of my hand, the touchpad move erratically.

Can somebody help me with my problem. I don't know what to do. I don't know if the problem with my charger damaged my battery, or the problem whit my battery affects the touchpad when the charger is plugged in.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should replace the battery to rule out the inflated battery being the cause of your problem with your touchpad

Comment: If I disconnect the internal battery, the problem continues. I just tried to run the computer without the battery and the problem still there.

Comment: Is the battery physically removed from the laptop, or just disconnected?

Comment: Physically removed to try what @Ramhound said